# Is there a way to index Hbase key with lily-hbase-indexer?

Tags: indexing, solr, hbase

I know that I can specify 'family:column' for lily to transform into Solr document field. But I need to pass Hbase row key into Lily mapper to extract some values from it. I don't want to add additional column that will duplicate row key(in this case I will need to add this column to all existing rows in Hbase to proper index them) so Is there a way to pass a row key to  tag in Lily indexer configuration?

Answer (score 0):

When you index the hbase row, to Solr document, then the id of the document is assigned the row key by default, unless you want to set it in your mapper class with a different value.

Comment: > unless you want to set it in your mapper class with a different value  - That's exactly what I need

Comment: Mean you need a different value to be set for the document id, other than Hbase rowkey? If yes, then I think you will always have a handle to SolrInoutDocuement and you can set your field using `document.addField("id", "1234")`. If still doubt, please add more details of exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually not Solr document id, I need to add field like this document.addField("id", "1234") only value should be a row key of Hbase result. We extended Default lily Solr but it's really pain, so I wonder if there's easier way to get row key to map to Solr field

Answer (score 0):

Finally found solution. Just copy Document ID filed into another field with custom Parser